# mysql return valid nth multiples results

Tags: mysql

I know there's similar questions but none seem to apply as to what I want to do.

Given the following query that returns lets say 85 results.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE person = 'Tom';
```

And I have another query that's similar but returns 168 results.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl_name WHERE person = 'Bob';
```

I'm trying to get results in valid multiples of 50.

By just changing `person` value in the `WHERE` clause I want to have the expected output of Tom's 1st, 50th results. Which means 2 row results total.

Likewise `Bob` would have returned the 1st, 50th, 100th, 150th result. Which is 4 row results total.

Is it possible to do this with just MySQL?

Comment: "output of Tom's 1st, 50th results" is that 2 rows or 50 rows?

Comment: By that I mean 2 rows in total. If it was 50 rows it wouldn't be an interesting problem otherwise ;)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Nailed it.  Change the 50 for different increments.  This assumes you meant that you wanted 1, 51, 101 (every 50th).

```
SELECT
    returnTable.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rowNumber,
        tbl_name.*
    FROM forum_posts,  (SELECT @rownum:=0) variableInit
    WHERE tbl_name.person = 'Tom'
) AS returnTable
WHERE returnTable.rowNumber = 1
OR (returnTable.rowNumber - 1) MOD 50 = 0;
```

If you actually want 1, 50, 100, 150 then the following does that (removed -1 from the WHERE)

```
SELECT
    returnTable.*
FROM (
    SELECT
        @rownum:=@rownum+1 AS rowNumber,
        tbl_name.*
    FROM forum_posts,  (SELECT @rownum:=0) variableInit
    WHERE tbl_name.person = 'Tom'
) AS returnTable
WHERE returnTable.rowNumber = 1
OR returnTable.rowNumber MOD 50 = 0;
```

Comment: Very, very nice. Thank you so much for your hard work! This was way over my head to try to do myself. :D

Comment: I hope you know it's 1:25 in the morning here ;) Was about to get some sleep and then this fun one popped up :D

Comment: Just implemented it on a custom query I had. Worked like a charm. Again, thanks for staying up one more second to check this question out ;) Very much appreciated!